# <c:if> tag within tables and render time

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, xhtml, javabeans

I'm quite new to JavaEE and XHTML and I hope you can help me.

I have some problems with the `<c:if>` tag and I know it must have to do something with the rendertime. So I have a table and I want to show a commandlink, not on all entries in the list, but on some which have a specific type or attribute.

Here goes my code:

```
 <h:dataTable id="list" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"
                                     value="${listbean.entryList}" var="entry" >
    <c:if test="${entry.eventType == 'Übung' or entry.eventType== 'Praktikum' }">
         <h:column>
            <h:commandLink action="#{listbean.deleteEntry()}" value="show event">
                       <f:param name="id" value="${entry.id}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
         </h:column>
    </c:if>
```

Is it possible to solve it?

Comment: what are "some problems" with the tag? Also, in which file you are writing this snippet, like `.jsp` or `.jspx` or `.html` or `.xhtml` or some other? Thanks.

Comment: Im using the xhtml file format and the problem is that this wont work. It seems like the if clause is allways false or true but there are different objects and it shouldnt be allways true or false.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that the `<c:if>` always returns either false for all entries or true for all entries? Have you printed all the values of the `entryList` - `entry` and `entry.eventType`?

Comment: i dont get your question ;). But i have other colums like eventName and there is allways a full list of all entrys. I want to have the entries with different event types to have different actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved it by useing some work arround.

I declared some boolean vars into the java code and used the EL to test if the values are true or false